# facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_InvalidUseException while using reltio connector in mule

Tags: java, mule, rsa, mule-esb

I am using `mule 3.8.3` and pulling an xml from weblogic queue and calling a reltio service through `reltio connector`. But I am facing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`: `com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_InvalidUseException error`.

Please help me in this. I have added `cryptoj.jar` in my class path but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes the issue after using the following variable/property in `mule-project.xml`

```
UseSunHttpHandler=true
```